# Cancel body background cover for other pages, except index.html in CSS

Tags: html, css

My HTML and CSS looks like this:

```css
/* GLOBAL */
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

body, html{
    min-height: 100%;
}

body{
    background-image: url('../img/owl1920.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}



.intro{
    padding-top: 15%;
    padding-left: 7%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.intro h1{
    font-size: 5vw;
    color: #F2EFC4;
    text-shadow: 6px 6px 20px #563300;
}

.intro p{
    font-size: 1.6vw;
    color: #563300;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.intro .hashtag{
    color: #F2EFC4;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #563300;
    /* text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #F2EFC4; */
}

.enter{
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.enter a{
    font-size: 1.2vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #F2EFC4;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #563300;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px #F2EFC4;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.enter a:hover{
    color: #563300;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #F2EFC4;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
    <title>Mkreativart | Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="intro">
           <h1>mKreativart</h1>
           <p class="motto">creativitate, imaginație, <span class="hashtag">#handmadegifts</span></p>
           <div class="enter">
               <a href="home.html">Intră pe site</a>
           </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

This should be my Welcome landing page.
Because my home page body background is already set in CSS as you can see, i will create the rest of the pages now but i would like to cancel the cover image set for the index.html (within CSS) and create a new layout.

Could someone please help me on this issue? 
Im still new to this and im not sure how to search for the issue. I tried already searching Stack-overflow but no success.

Comment: Do you use different URLs to load different pages or do you use AJAX to load new content?

Comment: im using only pure HTML5 and CSS3 to create the webpage

Answer (score 1):

How about applying these styles as a class on the homepage only `<body class="home">`?

```
.home {
    background-image: url('../img/owl1920.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Here's the page with the home class - https://jsfiddle.net/dkn2fvL4/1/

And without - https://jsfiddle.net/eoqca20t/1/

Comment: i will try this and get back with a feedback

Comment: Cool!  A good way to think of writing CSS is to think of the styles that will apply to the largest percentage of the site first and then add further classes for anything that will extend or differ from those defaults.  The homepage style in this case is the exception, so should come later in your stylesheet.

Comment: i have tried this already but for some reason the image will not fit as cover like in the picture above attached....it fits only half the page vertically.

Comment: and the thing is i dont want a background for any other pages other than the index.html

Comment: I've updated my answer - you don't need to set a background for the body - or could set a background-color property.